# This API is no longer supported. https://aka.ms/livesdkmigration for information about migrating your application to Microsoft Graph

Tags: php, api, microsoft-graph-api, live-sdk

How to integrate contact api to this code because graph API is such a headache to beginner , because recently the microsoft have migrated their api to graph API so please go through my code thank you

````
$url = 'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?access_token='.$accesstoken;/*this is a deprecated API*/

{
   "error": {
      "code": "api_deprecated", 
      "message": "This API is no longer supported. Please see https://aka.ms/livesdkmigration for information about migrating your application to Microsoft Graph."
   }
} ```
````

Comment: If you're using any legacy Live SDK or Live Connect APIs to connect to profile, calendar, contacts, or files, then your app needs to be updated to maintain functionality. Thats why you see the above error. Because they're deprecated (announced in 2017). Here's the migration documentation where you can get it started - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/migrating-from-live-sdk?view=odsp-graph-online.

Comment: Working with Microsoft Graph API is straightforward. You may want to get it started from here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/

Answer (score 0):

- If you're using any legacy Live SDK or Live Connect APIs to connect to profile, calendar, contacts, or files, then your app needs to be updated to maintain functionality. Thats why you see the above error. Because they're deprecated (announced in 2017). Here's the migration documentation where you can get it started [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/migrating-from-live-sdk?view=odsp-graph-online).
- Working with Microsoft Graph API is straightforward. You may want to get it started from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/).